# Ubuntu running .sh file - no such a directory or file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ffmpeg, directory

I am new to ubuntu/linux.

I try to follow this tutorial: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

When running bash file on step 3 I receive 'no such a directory or file' even though the directory does exists.

Comment: From the question _in it's current form_, anyone would say `No such file or directory`.

Comment: which exact command gives you the error? there are 2 commands in Step3.

Comment: Please include the full error message in your post.